# JS Performance of Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm vs Expression evaluation

Tags: javascript, performance, equality

Which expression inside if statement will be evaluated faster?

```
var test = true;
if( test == true ) {...}
```

OR

```
var test = true;
if( test ) {...}
```

Only got info about [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) and [The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)

Wanted to know more about how Truthy/Falsy values are evaluated.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example might be a bit faster (but since JS is today usually first compiled into a bytecode and only then evaluated, it's probable the generated bytecode will be the same in both cases).

It all starts with [The if statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.5). Its first step (and the only step that will differ in your examples) is to evaluate the expression within parentheses. In the second example, the expression is immediately evaluated to itself (true). In the first example, The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm, as you mentioned, will be used. It will make a few steps and return true from step 1.e.

In practice, I doubt the difference will be measurable.

Comment: I feel like for checking Truthy/Falsy we need to check type first, and then there there will be multiple if conditions executes anyway.
Just wanted to know which one should i use in my library.

Comment: If we change the question to "what should I use", then the answer definitely is the "if (test)" variant. From a performance point of view, it makes no difference. From a readability point of view, this is the notation that pretty much everyone else will be expecting.